# Finding a differential equation of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with exercice: **Find a differential equation whose solution is a family of straight lines that are tangents to the parabola $y^{2} = 2x$**

My ideas are:

To avoid confusion between the original curve and the variables of the straight line I'm writing parabola equation as:

$$y_0^{2} = 2 x_0$$

Tangent straight line equation is:
$$y-y_{0} = \frac{1}{y_{0}}(x-x_{0})$$

In this way I can't get correct result. The right answer should be:

$$2x(y′)^{2}−2yy′+1=0 $$

Could someone help me with solwing this problem?

I'll be very grateful

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = C$ be the point that you are taking the tangent line. For now, only consider the upper half of the parabola. You should be able to find the equation of the line:
$$y = 2C(x - C) + C^2 = 2Cx - C^2$$
From there, you can solve $C$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, then differentiate once.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Claraut's form differential equation where $c$ takes the place of derivative.

$$ x = c\,y- c^2/2 \tag1 $$

i.e.,

$$ x = y y^{\prime} - y^{\prime 2}/2 $$

To find envelope by C-discriminant (parameter) method partially differentiate (1) w.r.t. $c$

$$ 0= y - c,\quad y=c $$

and eliminate $c$ by plugging into (1) $c=y$ to get envelope

$$ y^2 = 2 x $$

However, the answer you gave

$$ 2 x c^2 -2 y c +1 =0 $$

by the above procedure gives for the $c$ parameter

$$ y = 2 x c $$

and same envelope

$$ y^2 = 2x $$

So the DE of the tangents to parabola may not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your tangent equation is correct.

$$y-y_{0} = \frac{1}{y_{0}}(x-x_{0}).$$

To get a differential equation, we evaluate $y'$ and get

$$y'=\frac1{y_0}.$$

Then we eliminate $x_0$ and $y_0$ by

$$y_0=\frac1{y'}$$ and $$x_0=\frac1{2y'^2},$$ giving the equation

$$y-\frac1{y'}=y'\left(x-\frac1{2y'^2}\right).$$

After cleanup,

$$2y'(y-y'x)=1.$$